# Same goto labels used in a C file but different functions

Tags: c, goto

Can someone please tell me if it is acceptable to use same goto labels in different functions in the same C file?

To explain what I am facing:

```
function1()
{
    ...

    goto label

    ...

label:
    ...
}

function2()
{
    ...

   goto label;

    ...

label:
    ...
}
```

Now whats happening is that the code after the label is being used for cleanup of malloc'ed' data. And the whole thing is crashing in function2. I printed out the mem. locations which are being free and the same are being freed multiple times. Is this because of all the gotos? Is this valid use of the goto statement?

Comment: Format your question properly, please.

Comment: try to post some code for getting actual problem...

Comment: You can have same label names in different functions but you can't use* label that's in another function. Your crash is not related to label name being re-used. There's something else wrong in your code which causes the double free.

Comment: There are probably better ways to clean up your data than by using goto. Don't get me wrong, there are times when goto is acceptable despite the bleating of the sheep who don't understand _why_ it was sometimes bad, but it should be used sparingly.

Comment: @paxdiablo it's accepted by the linux kernel people https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle but I suppose you know better?

Comment: @LtWorf, the kernel is a very specific piece of software where speed is _everything._ In most arenas, readability and maintainability should be forefront. In any case, you seem to have missed my point. "there are times when goto is acceptable". I did _not_ say you should never use it.

Comment: Freeing resources where you have several points when you can exit makes a function much more readable than copying and pasting the same code before every return.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Labels are local, so you can use the same label in multiple functions.

The question about if you should use `goto` is a different matter though, and one that is not easily answered. In short, don't use `goto`. But as with everything (especially when it comes to programming) there are exceptions where `goto` may be useful.

Comment: And the use of goto for cleanup tends to be one of them.

Comment: goto is used very frequently when the build-up/teardown is complex (ex: linux kernel) and various exit conditions would reuse the code from others (ex: allocate/release resources). In these cases using goto is cleaner and ensures that the fall-through mechanism will enforce exactly the same sequence across various stages of tear-down.

Comment: I used to say, "don't use gotos" until I learned that the linux kernel coding guide tells us to use them: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/process/coding-style.html.

Answer (score 13):

As Joachim said here, labels are local; but note that labels are local to functions - not to the current block. `goto` statements do not respect scoping, except for whole-function scoping.

Comment: If you're using GNU C, you can actually take advantage of the local labels extension (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Labels.html) which allows labels in nested blocks.